# JMeter: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: sockets, exception, connection, timeout, jmeter

Once a Login script is executed with few user, I don't see connection reset problem, whereas, when the same is run 100 users, "**java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**" starts throwing for very first link.

What I don't understand is if there is connection problem, then it should even show the same error for single or few users as well.

Comment: What is the web server you are using? Maybe the MaxConnection is set to a limited number

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case described in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page.

If you are absolutely sure that your server is not overloaded and is configured to accept 100+ connections (defaults are good for development, not for production, they need to be tweaked) you can try work it around as follows:

1. In *user.properties* file add the next 2 lines:

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
2. In *hc.parameters* file add the following line:

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```

   Both files live in JMeter's **bin** folder.
3. You need to restart JMeter to pick the properties up.

Above instructions are applicable for HttpClient4 implementation, make sure you use it, the fastest and the easiest way to set HttpClient4 implementation for all the HTTP Request samplers is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

This means that your server is rejecting connections because it is either overloaded or misconfigured.

It is regular that you don't face it with 1 user and face it with 100, this is typically what load testing brings, ie simulate traffic on your server