# Jmeter 2.13 throws connection reset error?

Tags: jmeter

Thanks for your support in advance.

It is from past two days I have started looking into JMeter 2.13 version to hit a application server component that accepts xml requests via http. I am targeting to hit with 5 million xml requests via Jmeter.

I did all the configuration and finally the error is

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tried a lot with all the options described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836008/jmeter-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset), and others as well, but no positive result.

Here I am attaching the jmx configuration, sample input file and other jmeter environment configuration files for your reference.

I am using Java 1.7 (cannot use 1.8 because of other restrictions)
Jmeter 2.13

By the way, the application runs on a port 10011 on a remote linux server where i am doing tunnelling thru putty and accessing that application.

Any help why this error is caused ? I tried with all the options but no positive result.

**hc.parameters**

```
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
```

**user.properties**

```
httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
```

**jmx file configuration**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" jmeter="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1506518262000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1506518262000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP Request" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${PATH}</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">9999</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout">60000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">Air/</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">Java</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">UGw Server/5.0/1.0</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Content-Type</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">text/xml</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Authorization</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">Basic Z3NkYzppbl9zaWRlX291dCE=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">user</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">fduser</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">password</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">fdsuser</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </HeaderManager>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="filename">C:\PentahoDataIntegration5.1\Airtel_Tanzania\jmetersetup\Create_DA_Product_Id_xml.txt</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames">PATH</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="delimiter">\n</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="recycle">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="stopThread">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
        </CSVDataSet>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>false</time>
              <latency>false</latency>
              <timestamp>false</timestamp>
              <success>false</success>
              <label>false</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>false</threadName>
              <dataType>false</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>false</assertions>
              <subresults>false</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>true</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">C:\PentahoDataIntegration5.1\Airtel_Tanzania\jmetersetup\Result_PCRF_UpdateBalanceAndDate.xml</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
    <WorkBench guiclass="WorkBenchGui" testclass="WorkBench" testname="WorkBench" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="WorkBench.save">true</boolProp>
    </WorkBench>
    <hashTree/>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Please help !

Comment: how many concurrent threads are you running? how quickly requests finish? did you check that you have enough ports to support number of [parallel request and request frequency?

Comment: The http server can accept only 80 connections per port (one port is available) and so i would like to run 80 threads in the thread group. Loop count = total number of requests / number of threads. Each request would finish less than 100 milliseconds. However the problem got resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Connection reset can mean a lot of things and many are due to server side, not JMeter side.

Among possible reasons:

- Any intermediate component overloaded, monitor them to see if it's the case
- Server overloaded, monitor it to see if it's the case
- JMeter overloaded, monitor it to see if it's the case

I would also advise you to **switch to JMeter 3.3, 2.13 is now 4 versions old and very old.**

And ensure you follow best-practices:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/